# List files in all subdirectories by creation date

Tags: files, search, timestamps

I have forgotten the name of a file which is in a directory or one of its subdirectories. I remember the file's extension (.nb) and know approximately when it was created. How can I list all file with this extension in the current directory and subdirectories along with their creation dates? I'm using Mac OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way to do this is with [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsh), which is installed by default on macOS. Its [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) let you select and sort files by timestamp and other metadata. Zsh doesn't support creation times, but it supports modification times and inode change times; one of them probably matches the creation time.

This lists the 100 (`[1,100]`) most recent (`om`) regular (`.`) files with the `.nb` extension in the current directory and its subdirectories (`**/`):

```
zsh -c 'ls -ltr **/*.nb(.om[1,100])'
```

This lists files modified between 7 and 14 days ago:

```
zsh -c 'ls -ltr **/*.nb(.m+6m-14)'
```

Answer (score 3):

This should accomplish what you want.

```
find . -type f -name '*.nb'|xargs stat -f '%c %N'|sort
```

## Explanation

`find . -type f -name '*.nb'` find all files with .nb extension.

`xargs stat -f '%c %N'` print out the files with the unix timestamp in the front.

`sort` sort it.

Comment: Creation date would be birth time in the mac world. You might consider replacing change time-`%c` with birth time-`%B`.

Answer (score 0):

For bash (not mac):

```
find . -type f -iname '*.nb'| xargs -d '\n' stat -c '%z %N'|sort
```

find all entries of type 'file' in the current directory and below, matching pattern

(-iname to ignore case)

pipe it to xargs

(-d '\n' change delimiter to linefeed to allow for spaces in file names)

then to stat

(-c for output format %z = last status change %N quoted file name)

and sort the output

Answer (score -1):

```
find -name '*.nb' -exec ls -rtl {} +
```

Will show detailed info on all files matching the pattern, and sort them from oldest to newest (you can have from newest to oldest by removing the `r` option from the `ls` command).

The `+` at the end means you execute the command at the end of the search instead of running it for each match.

**NOTE**: this will only work with a reasonable amount of matches, if the command line is too long for `ls` it will be split up in several `ls`'s, resulting in several sorted subsets while the whole list will not be sorted correctly (thank you @Gilles and @rudimeier for pointing it out).

Comment: This will not work if there are too many files from one single `ls` command.

Comment: @rudimeier Why is that ?

Comment: @ValentinB. Because if the command line is too long, `find` will execute `ls` several times, with successive subsets of the files to fit within the limit. Each subset will be sorted but not the whole.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Gilles. I will edit my answer accordingly.