# List of files with a certain suffix in my path and its subdirectories, listed with their last update date

Tags: files, solaris, search, timestamps

On a Unix server (Sun Solaris), with `ls -lrtR` I get the list of all the file in my path and its subdirectories with their last update date.

With `find . -type f -name "*.sas"` I find the list of my .sas files in my path and its subdirectories but without attributes.

Is it possible to have the list of my .sas files in my path and its subdirectories with their last update date?

I tried `find / -iname "*.sas"` from [How to find a file from any directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362292/how-to-find-a-file-from-any-directory) but it gives me:

```
find: bad option -iname
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
```

I tried `find . -type f -name '*.sas'|xargs stat -f '%c %N'|sort` from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320547/184179, but it gives me:

```
xargs: Could not exec command: No such file or directory
```

Comment: In most cases, citing your system details like FreeBSD, Solaris, GNU Linux and specific versions of your shell (bash/zsh/ksh/tcsh) might be useful

Comment: @Inian Solaris, added, thanks.

Comment: Note that the `-iname` argument is a non-portable, non-standard GNU extension to the [POSIX-standard `find` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/find.html).

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm not an expert, I tried what I found on the internet

Comment: Have you tried `find / -type f -name \*.sas -ls`?

Comment: @Lambert It gives a list but without the date.

Comment: Please post the value of `uname -a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the man page `man find` the `-ls` option can be used to show the modification time:

```
 -ls                 Always  true.  Prints  current  pathname
                     together with its associated statistics.
                     These include (respectively):

                         o    inode number

                         o    size in kilobytes (1024 bytes)

                         o    protection mode

                         o    number of hard links

                         o    user

                         o    group

                         o    size in bytes

                         o    modification time.
```

So in your case the command `find / -type f -name "*.sas" -ls` should output something like:

```
24584    1 -rw-r--r--   1 user staff           0 Oct  1 13:58 ./a.sas
24586    1 -rw-r--r--   1 user staff           0 Oct  1 13:58 ./b.sas
24587    1 -rw-r--r--   1 user staff           0 Oct  1 13:58 ./c.sas
```

Comment: It works, thanks!

Comment: Also, just for future usage, remember that  `find` also supports `-exec command_of_your_choice {} \; ` which allows you to run `command_of_your_choice` for each file matching. The  `{}` will be replaced by filename.